# Google Cloud: Cannot get the VM to use 96 CPUs

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a K8S cluster, running openfaas. I added a node pool with `n1-highcpu-96` instances. The one instance that I can see running in this pool, shows only 64 CPUs when I run `grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo`.

Not sure what happened to the remaining 32 CPUs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to the Container OS (COS) in use by GKE.
COS images in use by GKE won't support more than 64 CPUs. However, with Ubuntu you could use more than 64 CPUs.